# ¿Hay alguna manera de abrir varias carpetas (proyectos) en Brackets?

Tags: brackets

¿Es posible abrir varios proyectos al mismo tiempo en brackets?¿Conocéis algún módulo? Es un poco engorroso tener que estar abriendo proyectos cada vez que necesito algo y que se salga del proyecto en el que estoy.

Comment: Hola buenos días, por "tener que andar abriendo proyectos cada vez que necesito algo" te refieres a algo como en esta imagen? [imagen](https://ibb.co/f1krqn7)

Comment: Yo te propongo que uses Visual Studio Code, es muchísimo mejor editor de texto, desde mi opinión personal, y puedes hacer lo que necesitas y mucho mas

Comment: Hola, si @SebastiánMiranda  es a lo que me refiero, lo que busco sería algo así [imagen](https://ibb.co/dDSMP1q)
Pero me parece eso poco posible y no me sirve si quiero trabajar con varios proyectos al mismo tiempo... así que al final me tendré que cambiar de editor.

Comment: @sergio yo trabajo con sublime text y en mi caso en la barra se maneja como carpetas. Podrías ver la opción de Adriana y ver si te da la opción